# Can anybody please tell me how always parent class instance variable printed?

Tags: java

```
public class A{ 
    int x=20;
    public int getX(){
     return x;
    }
    public void setX(int x){
     this.x=x;
    }
}

public class B extends A{
    int x=10;
   public void setX(int x){
       this.x=x;
     } 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       B a=new B(); or A a= new B();
       a.setX(30);
       System.out.println(a.getX());/*it will always print parent class X*/
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't just post code, but also write your question along side it. Just putting the question in the title is not good practice and hurts readability.

Answer (score 6):

There is no `getX()` method  in B . It will always call the inherited method. If you want to simulate run time polymorphism , then you have to override the inherited methods in the subclass.

Answer (score 2):

Inorder to get the child functionality you have to ovveride the super class method in child class.

So,code changes to

```
public class B extends A{
    int x=10;
   public void setX(int x){
       this.x=x;
     } 

  @override
  public int getX(){
    return 6;  // here you overridden that method  return your new value here 
   }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       B a=new B(); or A a= new B();
       a.setX(30);
       System.out.println(a.getX());/*new value prints*/
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 Comprehensive but still sweet :)

Comment: please explain how this java code works in the background. What happens when getX() method is invoked and why is it so behaving?

Comment: Actaully its concept of inheritance and method ovverriding in java.Please read oracle docs about those 2 topics.Here we cannot explain all those concepts.I am assuming you are a beginner so read docs as much as possible. :)  good luck.